# How can I compile and run a C program (with OpenMP) in gem5 Full System?

Tags: openmp, gem5

I am an undergraduate student working on my thesis about parallel programming.
I am using OpenMP model. Now i want to use gem5 for measure performance.
That's why i install gem5 Full System successfully by following link:

http://cearial01.kaist.ac.kr/index.php/2016/08/26/gem5-documentation/

Now i want to compile & run a c program with OpenMP (matmul.c) using gem5.
How can i compile & run this program?
I mean inside which folder i stored this program file (matmul.c) for compile?
How i create object file of this program?
How can i change no of processor, cache memory size, no of cpu during running & compilation?

I am new student of this section. That's why my asking list is too big!
Hope anybody don't mind.

Best Regards,
Litu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run OpenMP code in gem5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636993/how-to-run-openmp-code-in-gem5)

Comment: Do not just repost a question if you get no response. Think how to make it more clear, specific and easier to answer.

Comment: You have many questions in your post, that is not good. Here we solve mainly specific problems. If you receive an error message and you don't know why, that is a good question. Asking a full tutorial is not a good question and can be closed as **too brad** or **unclear**.

Comment: @Zulan Link goes to Page Not Found

Answer (score 1):

> How can I compile and run this program? I mean inside which folder I stored this program file (matmul.c) for compile? How I create object file of this program?

How to cross compile for an image is not gem5 specific, so I'll be brief.

First you must obtain a cross compiler for the image.

The best way to do that, is to get a cross compiler from the same source as the image to ensure compatibility.

My preferred approach is to use minimal Buildroot images. Buildroot:

- builds both the cross compiler and the image for me, and thus ensure compatibility
- makes it easy to automate building new software with its package system
- can produce very simple images, which are more suitable for gem5 and architecture research

This is [my setup on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/e208cc15ebcd0b369053ae8831c4a984f2d106f9#gem5). It contains a minimal [OpenMP hello world](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/e208cc15ebcd0b369053ae8831c4a984f2d106f9/kernel_module/user/openmp.c) which I have successfully run inside of gem5.

Another good option is to use https://crosstool-ng.github.io/

Since you want OpenMP support, you must build the GCC cross compiler compiler with support.

I think this is done in GCC with:

```
./configure --enable-libgomp
```

or through the Buildroot option:

```
BR2_GCC_ENABLE_OPENMP=y
```

And then when compiling, you must pass the `-fopenmp` option to `gcc`.

> How can I change the number of processors and the cache memory size?

The best way to answer that question yourself is to use something like:

```
./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py -h
```

and search the options.

You come across:

- `-n NUM_CPUS, --num-cpus=NUM_CPUS`.

  For ARM you also need to pass a `.dtb` with the corresponding core count, e.g.: `./system/arm/dt/armv7_gem5_v1_2cpu.dtb` for 2 cores.
- caches: you will find the following options easily:

  ```
   --caches --l1d_size=1024 --l1i_size=1024 --l2cache --l2_size=1024 --l3_size=1024
  ```

  But keep in mind that:

  - the Linux kernel does not see the cache sizes correctly as of fbe63074e3a8128bdbe1a5e8f6509c565a3abbd4
    [How to switch CPU models in gem5 after restoring a checkpoint and then observe the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011096/how-to-switch-cpu-models-in-gem5-after-restoring-a-checkpoint-and-then-observe-t)
  - caches only affect certain CPU types, usually the more detailed such as ARM `HPI` and x86 `DerivO3CPU`, but not `AtomicSimpleCPU`.