# How to take a checkpoint at a given tick and then restore using the gem5 Python API?

Tags: gem5

I had always done with an [m5 checkpoint m5op + `fs.py -r`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011096/how-to-switch-cpu-models-in-gem5-after-restoring-a-checkpoint-and-then-observe-t). I then also learned that `fs.py` has `--take-checkpoints` which can select the tick.

But today I needed to do it for an [integration Linux boot test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279971/how-to-run-the-gem5-unit-tests/52279972#52279972) (`tests/gem5/fs/linux/arm/run.py`) to start running closer to the point of interest, and I don't want to modify the kernel to add the m5op + the runner script does not have `-r`/`--take-checkpoint` options. I wish this stuff were gem5.opt options available to all runs rather Python script options, but they're not.

Answer (score 0):

On gem5 71b450fc46ca5888971acf3160b813bf24784604 the script original script does:

```
m5.instantiate()
exit_event = m5.simulate()
```

so to take the checkpoint I can hack it to:

```
m5.instantiate()
# Run up to desired tick.
exit_event = m5.simulate(100000)
m5.checkpoint('m5out/mycpt')
```

and to restore hack it to:

```
m5.instantiate('m5out/mycpt')
exit_event = m5.simulate()
m5.checkpoint()
```