# fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory using arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi (crosstool-ng)

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, crosstool-ng

It seems that any gcc created with crosstool-ng is missing omp.h, is there a way to solve this issue?

```
tomas@ubuntu:~/eHHAlgorithm/infoli_static$ /home/tomas/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc infoli.c main.c -o infoli_arm_ns100_ss10_noout_nobench -lm -O3 -DNETWORK_SIZE=100 -DSIMULATION_STEPS=10 -DNO_OUTPUT -DNO_BENCH -static
infoli.c:3:10: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <omp.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

If I use `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, which I installed with apt-get directly in Ubuntu I don't get this error.

Comment: Did you try to add `-fopenmp` option to `gcc`?

Comment: When building crosstool-ng, did you enable openmp? (`./configure --enable-libgomp`) see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49023600/1212012

Comment: @purplepsycho I tried compiling my program with -fopenmp, yes. It seems the issue is the configure for crosstool-ng, I didn't enable openmp... Do I need to re-compile everything from scratch?

Comment: `--enable-libgomp` doesn't work for me: `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-libgomp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

`./ct-ng arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi`

`./ct-ng menuconfig -> C compiler -> Compile libgomp` (enable pressing < y >). Save changes.

`./ct-ng build`

This will enable the `LIBGOMP` option in the `.config` file:

```
tomas@ubuntu:~/crosstool-ng$ grep LIBGOMP .config*
.config:CT_CC_GCC_LIBGOMP=y
.config.old:# CT_CC_GCC_LIBGOMP is not set
```